# CSS3 ignore Child element when animating

Tags: html, css

I am trying to scale a div containing a child div (with css background image) on hover. When I scale the div, the child div is also scaled. How can I get the child div to not inherit the animation of the parent? See my structure and fiddle here:

```
<div style="background:#000;">
    <div class="icon-wrap icon-effect">
       <a href="#">
          <div class="icon">
              <div class="arrow-down"></div>
          </div>
       </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B8bGE/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked around this by doing the following:

```
    <div class="icon-wrap icon-effect"> <a href="#">
                                            <div class="icoback">
                                            <div class="icon">
                                            </div>
                                                <div class="arrow-down"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>

    </div>
```

Then applying some css to .icoback. See the fiddle for details: http://jsfiddle.net/xtW22/2/

Comment: If that answers your question you should accept it as the correct answers with the green V button